# Java BufferedReader - the last line of output isn't read automatically, it reads only when i press enter

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

This is my code:

```
public class hack 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader sc = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int count = 0;
        int cases = Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine());
        String pie = "31415926535897932384626433833";
        String str;
        for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++)
        {
            str = sc.readLine();
            String []strarr = str.split(" ");
            String str1 = "";
            for(int k = 0; k < strarr.length; k++)
            {
                char check[] = strarr[k].toCharArray();
                count = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < strarr[k].length(); j++)
                {
                    if((check[j] > 64 && check[j] < 91) || (check[j] > 96 && check[j] < 122))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                str1 = str1 + count;
            }
            if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase(pie.substring(0,strarr.length)))
            {
                System.out.println("It's a pi song.");
            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println("It's not a pi song.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The input file is as follows :

```
4<br>
dHjVPihCZ BjHi OkWbQBH NIQM Ue BPIJHS ZdWQLMIxy wzVGBhx GqQjKMeJ ZmfZo l qmDWBUrs<br>
YkoGQTJYN vgy tJ k B g YV T iXExLPfFk eL TTcOtic MRbmKE<br>
RMSIYuD GiRYQ U K THGUT XYycRULD pTG NqlHUO RFEG rJ sqcGVd jZ IhTlGUvE FLQfISMqN cW<br>
Rzm YPPGEQDXq PsDpNLCd qLTFiFDn wFqpGvSB YQqIZY sfWRwGJ<br><br>
```

The output is as follows :

```
dHjVPihCZ BjHi OkWbQBH NIQM Ue BPIJHS ZdWQLMIxy wzVGBhx GqQjKMeJ ZmfZo l qmDWBUrs<br>
YkoGQTJYN vgy tJ k B g YV T iXExLPfFk eL TTcOtic MRbmKE<br>
RMSIYuD GiRYQ U K THGUT XYycRULD pTG NqlHUO RFEG rJ sqcGVd jZ IhTlGUvE FLQfISMqN cW<br>
It's not a pi song.<br>
It's not a pi song.<br>
It's not a pi song.<br>
Rzm YPPGEQDXq PsDpNLCd qLTFiFDn wFqpGvSB YQqIZY sfWRwGJ<br>
it's not a pi song.
<br><br>
```

In this I have given 4 as no. of cases. As input I gave all four lines together, but it considered only first three lines as input and only their output is shown together, I want the output of all four lines to be shown together.

Comment: Is this reproducible? To me it just looks like dependant on the timing of entering text and outputting the result.

Comment: It looks like the output should only contain "It's a pi song" and/or "It's not a pi song.". You appear to have shown input intermingled with the output (excluding  the initial "4", for some reason). How are you running this so that the input also goes to the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have another line feed after your last input line.  `BufferedReader.readLine()` javadoc:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.